# Rails url_for hash with 'protocol' key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm trying to add parameters to the current path through hash:

```
url_for(@params.merge({'protocol' => 1}))
```

but it seems that Rails filters protocol hash key and the result has no protocol parameter.
How can I add it to the current path?

Comment: `protocol` is an anticipated key in `url_for` to specify the web protocol e.g. `http`,`https`, `ftp` etc. if you wanted to implement your own query parameter why not call it something other than "protocol"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used next oneliner to solve protocol option issue:

```
url_for() + '?' + @params.merge({:protocol => 1}).to_query
```